# How can I stop banshee from downloading podcasts as 'read only'

Tags: permissions, banshee, podcast

When Banshee downloads podcasts to the 'Podcasts' folder, it marks that folder as read only. This is a problem when I want to sync them to my Android smartphone and I am unable to listen to them because of this permission setting. I am able to change the permissions of the folder manually, but when it updates the feeds, it resets them.

I've found a few threads about the internet, including the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1051424), but no-one is able to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a case like this, the best bet is to report a bug in banshee's bug tracker. If the bug is fixed, you'll get the update in the next release.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else this affects, like me, the bug report can be found here:

[Bug #682971: Podcasts are downloaded as 'Read Only'](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/+bug/682971)

(Just click the this bug affects me too link)